# Changing PDF appearance

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, pdf

We need some changes done in the PDF that magento gives. I've looked at many guides and have found some solutions that work but are not really how I want it to be done. Many guides tell you to copy the files you want to edit, paste it in the local folder and make your changes there. But the changes are really small so I wanna know if there is a better way to make these small changes. The changes have to be done in these 2 files.

```
App/code/Mage/Core/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php
App/code/Mage/Core/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php
```

And all that we are going to change on these files are some colours. We could also override these classes but one of the classes is an abstract class. I am not sure if it's right to extend these and change them in local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inchoo published an article about rewriting code classes. It will minimalize the impact of your changes

`Config.xml`

```
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <sales>
                <rewrite>
                   <order_pdf_invoice>[Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Sales_Order_Pdf_Invoice</order_pdf_invoice>
                </rewrite>
            </sales>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Link to the article: http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/

**important**

You can't rewrite an abstract class, you will need to rewrite the classes that use the abstract class copying the method you want to rewrite to the new class and add your changes there

Comment: Would I also have to follow these steps if I want to override methods? All I am doing here is changing some simple colours in the methods in that class. (mainly talking about the abstract class). What is the best practice here?

Comment: Jup, specially for overwriting methods. Its the only way to do it