# How to override a method of abstract file of invoice pdf

Tags: magento-1.9, override-model

I want to override a method insert Totals of this file :-  `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php`

How can I do that? Can anyone please guide?

I saw this post : **[Changing PDF appearance](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/61066/changing-pdf-appearance)**  which is quite good but still can't understand which file to make, where to make etc... We have our custom module in which we can do the stuff but I can not understand which file to make & where to put to override abstract class method.

Can anyone please guide step by step implementation of this?

Here is the further update :-
What I tried is : in my config.xml file I put this :-

```
<sales>
<rewrite><order_pdf_invoice>Promotion_Multidiscount_Model_Sales_Order_Pdf_Invoice</order_pdf_invoice>
</rewrite>
</sales>
```

And I copied code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php in my module's folder that is code/local/Promotion/Multidiscount/Model/Sales/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php & I modified that particular function only & kept rest of the functions as it is but now this error coming when I go to Invoice of any order & click Print button.

Error :-

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getPdf() on boolean in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_store/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Sales/Invoice.php:119 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_store/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/InvoiceController.php(489): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Sales_Invoice->printAction() #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_InvoiceController->printAction() #2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('print') #3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http)) #4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch() #5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_store/app/Mage.php(683): Mage in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_store/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Sales/Invoice.php on line 119
```

Url is like this :-
http://localhost/magento_store/index.php/admin/sales_order_invoice/print/invoice_id/43/key/be7b6b59159f5523398350f73d1236c2/

Thank you.

Comment: Any guidance please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the things were correct except one - Folder structure.
I did a mistake by placing an overriding file in sales folder in model folder of my module.

I wanted to override a method insertTotals inside the following file app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Abstract.php

So in my module's config file I did a change :-

```
<sales>
<rewrite><order_pdf_invoice>Promotion_Multidiscount_Model_Sales_Order_Pdf_Invoice</order_pdf_invoice>
</rewrite>
</sales>
```

But in my module, I put Invoice.php file here `app\code\local\Promotion\Multidiscount\Model\Sales\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php`

Actually it should be here

```
app\code\local\Promotion\Multidiscount\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do compare/confirm config.xml code and Invoice.php file directory structure. Following cod working for me.

open your module config.xml (example: app/code/Your/Module/etc/config.xml)

And Fine models Node then add within models node like below.

```
<models>
     <sales>
          <rewrite><order_pdf_invoice>Your_Module_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice</order_pdf_invoice>
          </rewrite>
     </sales>
</models>
```

After that you need to create directory within Model directory like below

Your/Module/Model/Order/Pdf/

And Place Invoice.php.

Make sure you need to change class name and extend class name like below

**class Your_Module_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice**

Hope it will work

Then

Comment: Thank you Mohammad for answering :) but I marked my answer as accepted because I found the issue & already posted here before your's :)
But the important thing is that at-least I get the knowledge of how to override abstract class's method :) But thank you for answering :)